# What is the correct time complexity for n factorial time funcion?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am very new to this topic and I am trying to grasp everything related to the asymptotic notations. I want to ask for your opinion on the following question:

If we have, for an algorithm, that **T(n)=n!**, then we can say for its time complexity that:

```
1 x 1 x 1 ... x1 <= n! <= n x n x n ... x n
```

This relation means that n! = O(n^n) and n! = Ω(1). However, can't we do better? We want the big-oh to be as close as we can to the function T(n). If we do the following:

```
n! <= 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 ... x n x n
```

That is, for the second to last element, we replace (n-1) with n. Now isnt this relation true? So isn't it true that n! = O(1 x 2 ... x n x n)? Something similar can be said for the lower bound Ω.

I am not sure if there is an error in my though process so I would really appreciate your input. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. What you are saying is true but how does that help you? In fact  n!=o(n^n) (little oh) and n!=w(2^n)

Comment: Thanks for reply. What I am asking is, given a time compelxity function T(n)=n!, how should I describe its big-oh? O(n^n) is the obvious answer as I have described but, dont we want the upper bound to be as close as possible to the T(n)? If we can say that n!=O(1 x 2 ... x n x n) isnt that preferable to saying n!=O(n^n)?

Comment: You describe it by saying is \Theta(n!) which is as good as any description. Now if you want to compare your algorithm with another which is \Theta(n^n) then you could say O(n^n). In fact as i mentioned before it is o(n^n) which means your algorithm is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mathematical statement `n! = O(1 x 2 ... x n x n)` is true. But also not terribly helpful nor enlightening. In what situations do you want to write `n! = O(...)`?

Either you are satisfied with `n! = n!`, and you don't need to write `n! = O(1 x 2 ... x n x n)`. Or you are not satisfied with `n! = n!`; you want something that explains better exactly how large is `n!`; then you shouldn't be satisfied with `n! = O(1 x 2 ... x n x n)` either, as it is not any easier to understand.

Personally, I am satisfied with polynomials, like `n^2`. I am satisfied with exponentials, like `2^n`. I am also somewhat satisfied with `n^n`, because I know `n^n = 2^(n log n)`, and I also know I can't hope to find a better expression for `n^n`.

But I am not satisfied with `n!`. I would like to be able to compare it to exponentials.

Here are two comparisons:

```
n! < n^n
2^n < n!
```

The first one is obtained by upperbounding every factor by `n` in the product; the second one is obtained by lowerbounding every factor by `2` in the product.

That's already pretty good; it tells us that `n!` is somewhere between the exponential `2^n` and the superexponential `n^n`.

But you can easily tell that the upperbound `n^n` is too high; for instance, you can find the following tighter bounds quite easily:

```
n! < n^(n-1)
n! < 2 * n^(n-2)
n! < 6 * n^(n-3)
```

Note that `n^(n-3)` is a lot smaller than `n^n` when `n` is big! This is slightly better, but still not satisfying.

You could go even further, and notice that half the factors are smaller than `n/2`, thus:

```
n! < (n/2)^(n/2) * n^(n/2) = (1/2)^(n/2) * n^n = (n / sqrt(2))^n =~ (0.7 n)^n
```

This is a slightly tighter upper bound! But can we do even better? I am still not satisfied.

If you are not satisfied either, I encourage you to read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I think this makes me understand something. What I said is true, as you confirmed. But you say that it is more helpful to know that 2^n<n!<n^n. Is this true because the purpose of big-oh is to see if our algorithm has a smaller run-time than another well defined worse time function? Rather than bound it with an arbitrary function? In my case, saying that n! is bounded by a the random function 1x...x n x n doesnt help, but saying that its bound by n^n gives me something more tangible, more understandable. Are all these correct thoughts?

Comment: We want to bound `n!` by functions that are easier to understand than `n!`, but also, we want to bound `n!` by functions that are as close to possible to `n!`. Your function `1*...*n*n` is extremely close to `n!`, which is good, but it is also not at all easier to understand, so there is no benefit from using this function instead of `n!`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand it ! Thanks a lot for the answer and for the link, will check it soon. Also, your last word of the comment, you wanted to use n^n instead of n! there?